# CSS Class Links

Tags: css, class, hyperlink

I'm working on a site where I want to make different styles for different sets of links. I've read tutorials and I still can't get my code to work. So here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
a.test: link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
a.test: hover {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #6F0;
 }
a.test: active {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #90F;
}
a.test: visited {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FF0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
Emily

<p>sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
sdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjlsdkf
<p><span class="test"><a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html">rose</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html" class="test"> daisy</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html" class="test">tulip</a> 

  <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html" class="test"> cactus</a>     </span>
<p>ldkfjsldkfjlsdkfsdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjs    ldkfjsldkfjlsdkfsdlkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsldkfjsld



</body>
</html>
```

From what I've read, I understand I need to incorporate a class into the link style like this: a.test:link

And to incorporate the style into the link you give it a class like this,
   cactus

And I can't figure out why this isn't working.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You already gave the `<a>` a class, use it directly, `.test{ }`

Comment: Where it says Cactus, I meant to point at one of the links, ( <a href="http://www.ehow.com/how_2080242_style-link-css.html" class="test">) cactus(</a>)

Comment: @ali bassam where do I use it directly? Could I have a context please?

Comment: just remove the `a` from `a.test` to make it `.test` since you gave this class to an element, you don't have to use it in CSS: If you had `<div class="hello"></div>` , then reach it in CSS using: `.hello { color:red; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to omit the spaces in your rules:

```
a.test:link {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #C00;
}
a.test:hover {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #6F0;
 }
a.test:active {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #90F;
}
a.test:visited {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    color: #FF0;
}
```

I don't expect that this pseudo classes allows a space in their names.

By the way you can reduce you CSS to this:

```
a.test {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
a.test:link {
    color: #C00;
}
a.test:hover {
    color: #6F0;
 }
a.test:active {
    color: #90F;
}
a.test:visited {
    color: #FF0;
}
```